# PHP - Is it possible to return the return command?

Tags: php, return

Say we have:

```
function foo() {
    bar();
    echo "hello stackoverflow, this is my first question, you helped me so many times, I can't even count it, you are great! <3";
}
function bar() {
    return;
}
foo();
```

I know it's rude but is it possible to let `bar()` return a "return command" like `return return;` to tell `foo()` to immediately return aswell? I know you can do it with a check in `foo()` if you set a specific return value in `bar()`, but is it possible without in some way?

Comment: no thats not possible. i would avoid using goto or throwing exceptions for this

Comment: A local function is isolated from the parent function. The best way to stop execution of a parent process is throwing an exception, but it needs to be managed in the parent call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No because Simply after `return` no statement of function execute.

And `return return` is a

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'return'

Very nice explanation of `return` in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)